# Multiple Audio Player

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

can someone please tell me how I could program a small app with page turning effects (sound).
I want I someone click on the Next button the sound plays for 1sec and takes me to the second page, and from the second page, if you click on the Back button, another sound plays for 1sec and takes you back to the original page.
Somehow I'm having a problem, when I click on the back button the simulator crashes with a "autorelease" error message. Please find below .h and .m file . Thanks for taking the time to read.

This is the .m file for the 1st page

```
#import "_0_RabbanasViewController.h"
#import "Rabbana2.h"
#import "InfoPage.h"

@implementation _0_RabbanasViewController



- (IBAction)info {

    // This part takes us to the info page
    InfoPage *info = [[InfoPage alloc] initWithNibName:@"InfoPage" bundle:nil];
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"flipView" context:Nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:2];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView:self.view cache:YES];
    [self.view addSubview:info.view];
    [info release];
    [UIView commitAnimations];


    // This part plays the next page turn noise
    NSURL *this = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/next.wav", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];
    NSError *error;
    pagePlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:this error:&error];
    [pagePlayer setDelegate:self];
    pagePlayer.numberOfLoops = 0;
    [pagePlayer play];
    //[pagePlayer release];

    //This will stop the music when turning page
    [audioPlayer stop];
    [audioPlayer release];
    clicked = 0;
    [start setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Pplay.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}

- (IBAction)next {

    // This part takes us to the next view
    Rabbana2 *next = [[Rabbana2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"Rabbana2" bundle:nil];
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"flipView" context:Nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:2];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView:self.view cache:YES];
    [self.view addSubview:next.view];
    //[next release];
    [UIView commitAnimations];



    // This part plays the next page turn noise
    NSURL *this = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/next.wav", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];
    NSError *error;
    pagePlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:this error:&error];
    [pagePlayer setDelegate:self];
    pagePlayer.numberOfLoops = 0;
    [pagePlayer play];
     //[pagePlayer release];

    //This will stop the music when turning page
    [audioPlayer release];
    clicked = 0;
    [start setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Pplay.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 

}

// This button plays the audio
- (IBAction)play {

    if(clicked == 0){
        clicked = 1;
        NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/rabbana1.wav", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];

        NSError *error;
        audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
        [audioPlayer setDelegate:self];
        audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = 0;


        [audioPlayer play];
        [start setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Sstop.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    } 
    else{
        [audioPlayer stop];
        [audioPlayer release];
        clicked = 0;
        [start setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Pplay.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    } 

}

//If user does not do anything by the end of the sound set the button to start
- (void) audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying: (AVAudioPlayer *) player
                        successfully: (BOOL) flag {
    if (flag==YES) {
        clicked = 0;
        [start setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Pplay.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}
/*
// If user click on the next button while audio playing, Audio should stop
- (void) audioPlayerDidNotFinishPlaying: (AVAudioPlayer *) player
                                success: (BOOL) flag {
    if (flag==YES) {
        [audioPlayer stop];
        [audioPlayer release];
        clicked = 0;
        [start setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Pplay.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}
*/

- (void)dealloc
{

    [super dealloc];
    //[self.pagePlayer.delegate = nil];
    //self.AVAudioPlayer = nil ;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle


// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [scroll setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [scroll setContentSize:CGSizeMake(275,445)];
}


- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    //[audioPlayer release];
    //[pagePlayer release];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

@end
```

This is the .m file for the 2nd page

```
#import "InfoPage.h"
#import "_0_RabbanasViewController.h"


@implementation InfoPage

- (IBAction)back {
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"flipView" context:Nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown forView:self.view.superview cache:YES];

    [self.view removeFromSuperview];
    [UIView commitAnimations];

    // This part plays the back page turn noise
    NSURL *this = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/back.wav", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];
    NSError *error;
    pagePlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:this error:&error];
    [pagePlayer setDelegate:self];
    pagePlayer.numberOfLoops = 0;
    [pagePlayer play];

    //This will stop the music when turning page
    [pagePlayer release];
    clicked = 0;


}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
   // [InfoPage dealloc];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
   // [pagePlayer release];
    self.view = nil;
    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [scroll setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [scroll setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320,480)];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];

    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

@end
```